# How do I show data in an asp:label?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to show a value from a database into a asp:label. I can show the data into a dropdownlist but not into a asp:label.

This works:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="code" runat="server" DataSourceID="onlymonths" 
                        DataTextField="itemCode" DataValueField="itemCode"> 
                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

I have tried to do it as follows but no luck:

```
 <asp:Label ID="code" runat="server" DataSourceID="onlymonths" 
                        DataTextField="itemCode" DataValueField="itemCode"> 
                    </asp:Label>
```

So does anyone know how to show the value into the label?

Comment: Set the `Text` property of the label to show data in the label.

Comment: If you have a group of controls all on one page, consider using a List View. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx You can bind all of your data at once.

Answer (score 0):

asp labels are not databound controls like dropdownlists or gridviews, you would be better off writing a method to get at the data and populating the label manually something like this

```
   using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
while (rdr.Read())
{
    mylablel.text = rdr.GetString(0);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to change id of code of lable to lblCode since your drop down list id is code
Then write the following code

```
lblCode.Text =  code.SelectedItem.Text;
```